# Dynamically Change Visualization Type in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, is there a way of having a dashboard that, based on the content of the data that it is retrieving, dynamically displays a different type of visualization?

For example, if a single visualization is retrieving data from a single set of tables, the visualization type could dynamically change from pie chart to text table based on some condition:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do something similar to that using Bookmarks and Buttons.

In practice, you will need to put all the different visuals in the same point over each other, and show only one of them using different bookmarks. The bookmark selection is controlled using some buttons.

[Here](https://radacad.com/bookmarks-and-buttons-making-power-bi-charts-even-more-interactive) is a tutorial about how to set it up

It won't be fully dynamic since it requires a minimum of input from the user (to press a button or some other object) but I think it is the best you can do to achieve what you want.

To me, a big con of this kind of solution is that it will be less clear how the report works, also changing something (visuals, buttons, etc) managed in this way is way more time consuming when compared to a normal visual (or set of visuals)